# Using requests and Beautifulsoup to find text in page (With CSS)

Tags: python, css, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm doing a request to a webpage and I'm trying to retrieve some text on it. The text is splitup with span tags like this:

```
<span class="ed">This</span>
<span class="1">is</span>
<span class="12">jvgviehrgjfne</span>
<span class="dfe">my</span>
<span class="fd">gt4ugirdfgr</span>
<span class="df">string</span>
```

There are "inline style sheets" (CSS sheets) that says if we have to print or not the text to the screen and thus, not print the gibberish text on the screen. This is an example of 1 of the sheet:

```
.ed{display:inline}
.1{display:inline}
.12{display:none}
.dfe{display:inline}
.fd{display:none}
.df{display:inline}
```

but there are more CSS files like this.. So I don't know if there are any better way to achieve my goal (print the text that shows on screen and not use the gibberish that is not displayed)

My script is able to print the text.. but all of it (with gibberish) as the following: "This is jvgviehrgjfne my gt4ugirdfgr script!"

Comment: could you also post the python script what you have tried?

Comment: the css file makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you right, what you should do is to parse css files with regex for attributes associated with `inline` and provide the results to beautiful soup api. Here is a way:

```
import re
import bs4

page_txt = """
<span class="ed">This</span>
<span class="1">is</span>
<span class="12">jvgviehrgjfne</span>
<span class="dfe">my</span>
<span class="fd">gt4ugirdfgr</span>
<span class="df">string</span>
"""

css_file_read_output = """
.ed{display:inline}
.1{display:inline}
.12{display:none}
.dfe{display:inline}
.fd{display:none}
.df{display:inline}"""

css_file_lines = css_file_read_output.splitlines()

css_lines_text = []

for line in css_file_lines:
    inline_search = re.search(".*inline.*", line)
    if inline_search is not None:
        inline_group = inline_search.group()
        class_name_search = re.search("\..*\{", inline_group)
        class_name_group = class_name_search.group()
        class_name_group = class_name_group[1:-1] # getting rid of the last { and first .
        css_lines_text.append(class_name_group)
    else:
        pass

page_bs = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page_txt,"lxml")

wanted_text_list = []

for line in css_lines_text:
    wanted_line = page_bs.find("span", class_=line)
    wanted_text = wanted_line.get_text(strip=True)
    wanted_text_list.append(wanted_text)

wanted_string = " ".join(wanted_text_list)
```